# Accept Terms Field in DevDemon Subscriptions

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions

Looking for a solution to make users have to click a checkbox to accept the terms and conditions of our membership before being able to subscribe.

Would prefer some sort of required field solution rather than scripting something outside of the add-on.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used DevDemon's Subscription module personally but there does not appear to be a way to require certain fields outside of payment specific fields. Having said that the easiest approach would be to add an additional field to the template/s in question with a bit of javascript to see if the checkbox filed you added has indeed been checked before reenabling the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

[Zoo Visitor](http://www.ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor) (membership addon) has this functionality, and it plays well with Subscriptions